# Show that $\lim_n \int \vert f_n - f \vert d\nu = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space let $f$ and
> $f_1,f_2,\ldots$ be **nonnegative** real-valued $\mathcal{A}$-measurable
> functions on $X$ that are $\mu$-integrable.
>
> Suppose that they satisfy
>
> i) $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ $\mu$-a.e., and
>
> ii) $ \int f d\mu = \lim_n \int f_n d\mu$.
>
> Show that $\lim_n \int \vert f_n - f \vert d\nu = 0 $.

I'm thinking I want to bound $\vert f_n - f \vert $ from above $\mu$-a.e. by something $\mu$-integrable, independent of $n$, and use the DCT, but I'm not successful yet. Any hints?

Comment: Reminds me of Scheffe's theorem. In any case, what happens there is $|f-f_n| = (f-f_n) + 2 \max(f-f_n,0) $. One part is convergent, the other has a bound that uses the fact that $f_n$ is non-negative. I think [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149656) is close, perhaps enough to be a duplicate, but that depends upon you in any case.

Comment: That's a nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to adapt the proof of the DCT:

First notice that $|f_n-f|\leq |f_n|+|f|$ for all $n$, then consider
$$\int 2|f| = \int \liminf_n \left( |f_n|+|f| - |f_n-f| \right)\leq \liminf_n \left(\int |f_n|+|f| - \int |f_n-f|\right)$$
and therefore (since $f,f_n$ are non-negative and integrals converge)
$$\int 2f \leq \liminf_n \int f_n+f - \limsup_n\int|f_n-f| = \int 2f - \limsup_n\int|f_n-f|$$
and this implies
$$\limsup_n\int |f_n-f| \leq 0 \implies \lim_n \int |f_n-f|=0.$$